# A program to find the x values of a quadratic equation

Tags: c++

Given the values of a=1, b=5 and c=6, the values of x are supposed to be -2 and-3, but the following program gives the values of x as 6 and -11, which are incorrect. I'd be grateful if someone could figure out what's wrong with the program.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    char reply;
    int a,b,c,q,z;

    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter the value of a: ";
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"\nEnter the value of b: ";
        cin>>b;
        cout<<"\nEnter the value of c: ";
        cin>>c;

       q=(-b-(b*b-4*a*c)sqrt(b))/2/a;

       z=(-b+(b*b-4*a*c)sqrt(b))/2/a;

        cout<<"\nThe values of x are "<<q<<" and "<<z;
        cout<<"\nDo you want to find another values of x(y/n)?";
        cin>>reply;
    }
    while(reply=='y');

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you learn when you ran your code in the debugger, or added extra output to display the values of intermediate calculations?

Comment: what happens if 'a' is zero or very small? what happens if the user inputs a string?

Comment: What do *you* think `^` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
    q=(-b-(b^2-4*a*c)^1/2)/2*a;
    z=(-b+(b^2-4*a*c)^1/2)/2*a;
```

to

```
    q=(-b-(b^2-4*a*c)^1/2)/2/a;
    z=(-b+(b^2-4*a*c)^1/2)/2/a;
```

After you do that, change `b^2` to `b*b` (`^` is `xor`, not power)
and `b^1/2` to `sqrt(b)`.

And then, use `double` instead of `int`.

Comment: Please there's no b^1/2 to replace with sqrt(b), and per your suggestion I now have the following but I'm still getting the same old wrong answer.  q=(-b-(b*b-4*a*c)sqrt(b))/2/a;
                   z=(-b+(b*b-4*a*c)sqrt(b))/2/a;

Comment: ... instead of `(b^2-4*a*c)^1/2`, write `sqrt( b*b - 4*a*c )`.

Comment: Hurray! The program is now working perfectly. I'm so much grateful to you.

Answer (score 8):

The `^` symbol is actually the [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) operator, not a power or exponent operator, so `b^2` is actually `b xor 2`. Try `b*b` instead.

If you need to raise a base to a power exponent other than 2, you will need to use the `pow` function.

And use the `sqrt` function (in `<math.h>`) to calculate square roots instead of raising numbers to the power of 1/2.

Also, `a/b*c` is parsed as `(a/b)*c`, so you'll need either parenthesis:

```
   (...)/(2*a);
```

or do a second division:

```
   (...)/2/a;
```

Comment: When I was learning to program, the "^" operator definitely snuck up on me in this very uncomfortable manner. :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, change all the data types to `double`, otherwise `1/2` would give `0` instead of `0.5`.

Second, use `std::sqrt` from `<cmath>` header file.

then recall the formula, and compute it correctly.